# Drag and drop Outlook email problem with Kendo 2020 upload - deletes email in inbox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik

If I drag and drop an email, it works. However, instead of making a copy and uploading the email,  it pulls the email out of outlook completely and deletes the email in the inbox. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: It's been fixed in Kendo UI R3 2020 SP2 per https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/kendo-ui-r3-2020-sp2 .

Comment: There's also more info here: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/6086